# DOMContentLoaded not fired in popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, domcontentloaded

I'm opening a popup with

```
var popup = window.open(http://my.private.url/resource);
```

Here http://my.private.url/resource points to a service that return a simple html page.

The popup object is not null and I have access to the popup.document attribute.

The "opener" would like to be informed when the html page returned by the service is "ready". So, I did

```
var popup = window.open(http://some.url/resource);
// ...
popup.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /* some code here */});
```

The problem is: the 'DOMContentLoaded' event is not fired.

I'm using Google Chrome 73

There is no Same Origin Policy error here, because the opened url has the same origin as the opening script.

Any idea?
Thank you,
cheers

Comment: The `DOMContentLoaded` event of the popup will already have finished before you have the chance to add the event listener. Sharing data between different windows is kind of annoying. What are you trying to do? Depending on that, it might be better to include a script inside the popup or just use an ajax call to get the popup page instead of opening the page.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Unfortunately I must open that page in a new popup (is a project requirement) and I cannot modify the html page (the service implementation is not done by me). Moreover, the service response can be an html page sometimes, sometimes can be a pdf (it doesn't depend by me).

I would like to be informed when the service responded (with html or pdf).

There is no way?

Comment: What will you do with the page once it's open? Or do you just have to detect that it opened correctly? The 'simplest' way is to just use a `setInterval()` to loop every few (mili)seconds until you are sure something in the popup exists. For example, since I want to write to the body of the popup, I loop until `popup.document.querySelector( 'some-id' )` returns me the correct element. But there must be way better ways to do this.

Comment: Shilly, esactly.
I have just to detect that it opened correctly.
I implemented the loop in the setInterval, checking each second.

However, I also would like to know if there is a better way :)